# React.Js + Framer Motion animate only on initial page load

Tags: reactjs, animation, framer-motion

I am working on a React project where I have components animate in when they scroll in to view. I am using Framer Motion. How can I make it so the animation only triggers the first time you scroll by the component?

Right now, if I scroll down the page the animations work as expected. However, if I refresh or leave the page and come back the animations will fire again. Scrolling to the middle of the page, refreshing, and then scrolling back up will fire animations on components that were scrolled by before.

I understand this is the default behavior of Framer Motion going from initial value to animate value as components remount. I am looking to prevent this behavior on components that where in the users viewport before.

Sample code for one of the components is posted below. Any help is appreciated.

```
const Banner = ({ title, body, buttonStyle, buttonText, image, switchSide, link }) => {
  const { ref, inView } = useInView({
    threshold: .8
  })
  return (
    <motion.div className="banner" 
      ref={ref}
      initial={{  opacity: 0 }}
      animate={ inView ? {  opacity: 1 } : ''}
      transition={{ duration: .75 }}
    >
      <div className={`container ${switchSide ? 'banner-switch': ''}`}>
        <div className="side-a">
          <img src={ image } />
        </div>
        <div className="side-b">
          <h2>{ title }</h2>
          <p>{ body }</p>
          {
            buttonText
              ? <Button buttonStyle={buttonStyle} link={link} justify="flex-start">{ buttonText }</Button>
              : ''
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    </motion.div>
  )
}
export default Banner
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was faced with a similar problem lately. I was implementing intro animation and did not want it to trigger on every page refresh, so I have made a custom hook which saves a timestamp in local storage and on each page refresh compares saved time with stored timestamp and fires when the time has passed and stores a new value there. If you want to play it only once you could simply implement customize my code to store boolean and you’re good to go.

My custom hook

```
import {useEffect} from 'react';

const useIntro = () => {

const storage = window.localStorage;
const currTimestamp = Date.now();
const timestamp = JSON.parse(storage.getItem('timestamp') || '1000');

const timeLimit = 3 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 3 hours

const hasTimePassed = currTimestamp - timestamp > timeLimit;

useEffect(() => {
    hasTimePassed ? 
        storage.setItem('timestamp', currTimestamp.toString()) 
        : 
        storage.setItem('timestamp', timestamp.toString());
}, []);

return hasTimePassed;
};

export default useIntro;
```

You would need to make this simple change in your code

```js
const Banner = ({ title, body, buttonStyle, buttonText, image, switchSide, link }) => {
    const showAnimation = useIntro();


  const { ref, inView } = useInView({
    threshold: .8
  })
  return (
    <motion.div className="banner" 
      ref={ref}
      initial={{  opacity: 0 }}
      animate={ inView && showAnimation ? {  opacity: 1 } : ''}
      transition={{ duration: .75 }}
    >
      <div className={`container ${switchSide ? 'banner-switch': ''}`}>
        <div className="side-a">
          <img src={ image } />
        </div>
        <div className="side-b">
          <h2>{ title }</h2>
          <p>{ body }</p>
          {
            buttonText
              ? <Button buttonStyle={buttonStyle} link={link} justify="flex-start">{ buttonText }</Button>
              : ''
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    </motion.div>
  )
}
export default Banner
```

Hope this is what you were after.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! This is exactly the behavior i was looking for. Had to add showAnimation to initial. initial={{ showAnimation ? { opacity: 0 } : { opacity: 1 } }}

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. Please mark my answer as solved by clicking at checkmark below vote arrows :)

Answer (score 13):

Framer motion now has built in support for this now. Checkout this link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-animate-in-view-5-3-94j13

Relevant code:

```
function FadeInWhenVisible({ children }) {
  return (
    <motion.div
      initial="hidden"
      whileInView="visible"
      viewport={{ once: true }}
      transition={{ duration: 0.3 }}
      variants={{
        visible: { opacity: 1, scale: 1 },
        hidden: { opacity: 0, scale: 0 }
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </motion.div>
  );
}
```

Usage:

```
<FadeInWhenVisible>
  <Box />
</FadeInWhenVisible>
```

This makes sure that the animation occurs only once when the element comes into the viewport. We don't need the **[react-intersection-observer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-intersection-observer)** for checking if an element is in the viewport anymore!

Comment: Thank for this. Didn't know this existed but thought it should.  Thanks again.

Comment: This does not work if you go onto another page and come back, using react router.

Comment: @Snake_py I'm having this problem you mentioned. I'm using React Router and rendering the same component in several pages. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: No, the solution I went with was to track it myself.

Answer (score 4):

I made a small alteration to your hook so that it can track separate pages. Lets say you have visited the home page and animations have fired there, but you still want animations to fire on other pages.

```
import {useEffect} from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

export const useIntro = () => {

const location = useLocation()
const urlPath = location.pathname
const storage = window.localStorage;
const currTimestamp = Date.now();
const timestamp = JSON.parse(storage.getItem(`timestamp${urlPath}`) || '1000');

const timeLimit = 3 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 3 hours

const hasTimePassed = currTimestamp - timestamp > timeLimit;

useEffect(() => {
    hasTimePassed ? 
        storage.setItem(`timestamp${urlPath}`, currTimestamp.toString()) 
        : 
        storage.setItem(`timestamp${urlPath}`, timestamp.toString());
}, []);

return hasTimePassed;
};

export default useIntro;
```

Comment: Wow great! I think I might have I good use case for this and did not come up with this earlier. Thanks for sharing! 

Answer (score 2):

There's an API for that - the intersection observer API. And there's a React hook for using it, too - `react-intersection-observer`. I'm using that in a project right now - here I've extracted it as a custom hook

```
const useHasBeenViewed = () => {
  const [ref, inView] = useInView();
  const prevInView = useRef(false);
  const hasBeenViewed = prevInView.current || inView;
  useEffect(() => {
    prevInView.current = inView;
  });
  
  return [hasBeenViewed, ref];
}
```

And in use

```
const App = () => {
  const [hasBeenViewed, ref] = useHasBeenViewed();
  return (
    <motion.div animate={{opacity: hasBeenViewed ? 1 : 0}} ref={ref}>
      {hasBeenViewed}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The timestamp answers seem like an inelegant workaround to me when the intersection observer API is just for this.

Comment: How would you do this with variants?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a motion container and stagger children and {viewport: once} not working for you. Set {viewport: once} to parent motion container instead to children.
It helped me. Maybe will save someones time.

```js
<motion.div
        variants={containerVariants}
        initial="hidden"
        whileInView="show"
        viewport={{ once: true }} //here
        className="container"
      >
       <motion.div
              variants={itemsVariants}
              className={styles.gifContainerImage}
            >
             
            </motion.div>
            <motion.h3
              variants={itemsVariants}
              viewport={{ once: true }}
            >
             
            </motion.h3>
  </motion.div>

export const containerVariants = {
  hidden: {
    opacity: 0,
  },
  show: {
    opacity: 1,
    transition: {
      staggerChildren: 0.5,
      when: `beforeChildren`,
    },
  },
};
export const innerContainerVariants = {
  hidden: {
    opacity: 0,
  },
  show: {
    opacity: 1,
    transition: {
      staggerChildren: 0.5,
      when: `beforeChildren`,
      delay: 2.8,
    },
  },
};

export const itemsVariants = {
  hidden: {
    opacity: 0,
  },
  show: {
    opacity: 1,
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I was faced the same problem so this is how I solved it:

```js
const Projects = () => {
  const [hasBeenInView, setHasBeenInView] = useState(false)

  const { ref: lineRef, inView } = useInView({
    /* Optional options */
    threshold: 0,
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inView && !hasBeenInView) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setHasBeenInView(true)
      }, 2500 // animation duration in ms)
    }
  }, [inView, hasBeenInView])
  
  const lineVariants = {
    initial: ... // some code
    animate: {
      transition: { duration: 2.5, ease: 'easeOut' },
    },
  }

return <motion.svg
  variants={lineVariants}
  initial="initial"
  animate={(inView && !hasBeenInView) || hasBeenInView ? 'animate' : ''}
  ref={lineRef}
>
  <path d="M1 1C90.3285 53.6667 253.417 205.8 191.145 393C113.304 627 15.8551 744.5 206 1087"         stroke="#ffd300" />
  </motion.svg>
}
```